# Add-Type: command not found

Tags: powershell, shell, user-interface, add-type

I'm trying to create a basic GUI for PowerShell, but for some reason it can't recognize the Add-Type
parameter.
this is the code I've used:

```
# Init PowerShell Gui
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

# Create a new form
$LocalPrinterForm                    = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form

# Define the size, title and background color
$LocalPrinterForm.ClientSize         = '500,300'
$LocalPrinterForm.text               = "LazyAdmin - PowerShell GUI Example"
$LocalPrinterForm.BackColor          = "#ffffff"

# Display the form
[void]$LocalPrinterForm.ShowDialog()
```

when running it with: `$ ./exampleScript.ps1`

I get: `./exampleScript.ps1: line 2: Add-Type: command not found`

what can be the problem here?

Comment: Why the `$` ?? is that your powershell prompt?

Comment: There's no gac in powershell 7 if that's what you're using.  You'd have to put the full path to the dll after add-type.  Oh, nevermind it works somehow.

Comment: The error message is from your current shell (looks like bash), not powershell. Either add a shebang (like `#!/usr/bin/env pwsh`) on the first line of the script, or explicitly run pwsh, ie. `$ pwsh ./exampleScript.ps1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The add-type command is working fine with me I have version
5.1.18362.628

to find your PowerShell version type the following command:

```
$PSVersionTable
```